# Magento 2: How to setup Cron job correctly?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, crontab, cli

I have read all I could find about configuring the Magento 2 Cron jobs, and this is what I did:

```
crontab -u <myself> -e
```

And then added:

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/php/bin/php /web/bin/magento cron:run
*/1 * * * * /opt/php/bin/php /web/update/cron.php
*/1 * * * * /opt/php/bin/php /web/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

But it doesn't seem to be working...

```
/opt/php/bin/php
```

is what I get when I run

```
which php
```

but when I run

```
whereis php
```

I get

```
/usr/share/man/man1/php.1
```

Which one should I use as the < path to php binary >?

Am I missing anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to check the database, check the `cron_schedule` table in the `messages` field as this will tell you the return value of the cron task and what exception it returns (If any)

You can also log the cron output to a log file to ensure it's getting run correctly like so:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /path/to/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/update/cron.php >> /path/to/magento/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /path/to/magento/var/log/setup.cron.log`

My `which php` returns `/usr/bin/php` (Same as my crontab) so I'd stick with your `/opt/php/bin/php` but review the logs and database table as I mentioned above to see if anything else is being returned.